Import error for psycopg2 in lambda for fastapi + mangum application
I'm built a Fastapi + Mangum to deploy it in lambda. I'm trying to connect my application to postgresql, and I read all sorts of documentation, but I keep getting the same Import error every time I try to access the Function URL. Can some one please help me with this problem.
The error:

My last Dockerfile:
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.10

RUN yum install -y postgresql-devel gcc python3-devel

RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY src/ .

CMD ["app.handler"]

The requirements content:
requests==2.32.3
fastapi==0.115.3
mangum==0.19.0
pyjwt==2.9.0
cryptography==43.0.3
asyncpg==0.30.0

langchain-openai==0.2.3
langchain-aws==0.2.4
langchain-community==0.3.3
opensearch-py==2.7.1
langgraph==0.2.44
langgraph-checkpoint-postgres

PyYAML==6.0.2
uvicorn==0.32.0

